# Matlab to pdflatex with text properties

Tags: fonts, graphics, pdftex, scaling, matlab

I know that this might be more a detail rather than a serious problem but I've already Googled it like crazy and I can't find the solution.

Is it possible to achieve a MATLAB plot in `pdflatex` with the correct text properties of the document (namely size and fonts)? I'm able to achieve a polished figure through the `matlabfrag` and `ml2pdf` scripts but when I scale the figure width the text gets scaled as well. I'd like something sort of `Inkscape PDF+LaTeX` option that outputs a `.pdf_t` file and a `.tex` file with the text.

Comment: If you can relax the Matlab requirement and do your plots in [R](http://www.r-project.org), you can plot to TikZ with [tikzDevice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/index.html) which gathers font information via system calls to TeX when placing text.

Comment: You can do many fantastic plots by using the [`pgfplots`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots?sort=votes&pagesize=50) package of whose author is also active in here. It's much better if you try to narrow down your question context.  What is the data and which tool(MATLAB command) you normally use to plot?

Comment: @percusse Hey! Thanks for the suggestion of pgfplots. Usually I just have to plot lines and histograms but I've already used the "surf" command and I might need to do it again.

Comment: I've already tried the matlab2tikz script. I successfully created the tikz file but the latex file doesn't gets compiled. Probably because the plot I was testing was a surface.

Comment: Ben Hinkle's [exportfig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/727) script can write a .eps of the graphics and a separate .eps of the text, but that's not quite what you want. And matlab2tikz can produce surfaces, but if the surface has too many points, you can overrun TeX's capacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you very much for all the help.
I managed to find a fitting solution to this problem. I'll post here the solution in case someone else finds it useful. 
Basically I turned the tedious 2 steps task matlab-inkscape-PdfLateX into one single task. This is accomplished thanks to the plot2svg matlab function and through the inkscape export feature that can be run from the terminal shell or a script. Then I can run the script from Matlab through the ! invoke shell. Below is the script I created

#

```
echo "File name?"
read fname
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64;
inkscape $fname.svg -z -D --export-pdf=$fname.pdf --export-latex
rm $fname.svg
```

#

Answer (score 5):

You could consider to use [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022) script to export the figure from matlab into a tikz file that you could easly include in a latex document.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [**matlab2pgf**](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12962)? Give it a try. I suggest one should visit matlab central (file exchange) for applications like this.

Answer (score 1):

[LaPrint](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4638-laprint) takes a MATLAB figure and creates an eps file with place holders for the text and a TeX file which has the text.