# matlab figures with latex fonts

Tags: fonts, matlab

I realize this question might have been asked already, but I'm relatively new to LaTeX and matlab so I need some help.

I'm trying to export a figure for inclusion in my `tex` document (to be compiled using `pdflatex`). The figure contains axes labels with LaTeX fonts (`xlabel(...,'interpreter',latex)`).

I've looked extensevely on the web but have not found a satisfactory solution. 
My best solution so far is to produce a png file by using the `savefig.m` function, but the quality is not ideal

I'd be very grateful for any hints.

Comment: Matlab allows you to save figures in `eps` format, which maybe preferable over `png` format. I am not sure what you use in `savefig.m`, but saving figures can be done by `saveas()` command.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Matlab to pdflatex with text properties](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43301)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

These are the possibilities for you (I use the first two for my work):

**Way out 1**

You may try [matlab2tikz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022) and export your figures into `tikz` code.

**Way out 2**

Try [matfig2pgf](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12962) and get `pgf` code for your figure. matfig2pgf also provides a nice menu in the matlab figure window, thus some what more friendly.

**Way out 3**

If you a a PSTricks fan try [fig2texps](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25298-fig2texps-export-matlab-figure-to-latex) and get pstricks code.

**Way out 4**

Try [plot2svg](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7401)  and get svg diagrams. But this is somewhat over kill as you have to again find ways to insert svg figures into latex.

**Way out 5**

If you have surface plots, you may look at [surf2latex](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13146-surf-to-latex/content/surf2latex.m).

You can search for other applications in mathworks [matlabcentral/fileexchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?search_submit=fileexchange&query=tex&term=tex) and look for various (numerous) ways. Also use different key words like pgf, tikz, PSTricks, latex etc in your search on that page. Hope this is useful.

**How to get some peace of mind**

For all plotting needs you may start using `pgfplots`. Use matlab to get the datapoints from your program, and use `pgfplots` to plot. For details, see [pgfplots documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf). `pgfplots` can also be used with gnuplot seemlessly. Hence we can use the computing capabilities of gnuplot also.

**An example:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.0]
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x-$ label and some text,
            ylabel=$y-$ label
            ]
%
\addplot[domain=-10000:10000, no markers,green,ultra thick] gnuplot{14*x - x^2 + x^3 - x^4};
%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Some text to show the similarity of fonts in figures and main body.

\end{document}
```

You need to have `gnuplot` installed for this to work and enable `--shell-escape` option for `pdflatex`.

[image]

Comment: Or leave all these MATLAB begging methods and use [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) directly :)

Comment: @percusse: How did I forget that? :( Adding immediately to the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest some other options but they are not completely straightforward. You may give it a try.

Besides `savefig.m` there are popular tools at mathworks central that can export matlab figure such as [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629),[matlabfrag](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21286) and [laprint](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4638).

Out of them `matlabfrag` and `laprint` split the matlab figure into graphic stream  as`.eps` and  text stream as '.tex'. During latex->dvips->ps2pdf compilation the `PDF` of the figure with latex font embedded is done using `psfrag` package .

For a simple demonstration of `laprint` and `matlabfrag`see the link below 
[Matlab graphics with LaTeX](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/matlabandlatex.html) and [PDF document here](http://www.student.dtu.dk/~latex/downloadfiles/vejledninger/MatlabFigures.pdf). You may need [pstool](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11844/15717) package to make `psfrag` package work during `pdflatex` compilation.

For examples of `export_fig` can be found [here](https://sites.google.com/site/oliverwoodford/software/export_fig)

Search with some keywords and tags as shown in this link
https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=matlab+pdflatex

One of the related questions to this topic [What is the best way to include Matlab graphics?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3995/15717)

PS: I use `export_fig` and `matlabfrag` mostly.

**UPDATE:**
with mlf2pdf.m we can run the 'latex-dvi-ps-pdf compilation with psfrag commands' inside matlab. we dont need pstool or psfrag in latex document. here is the very less popular unknown magic function. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28545-matlabfrag-to-pdf

Answer (score 1):

I recently learned of another approach over at [MATLAB Answers](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/52340-why-do-deep-paths-in-usepackage-cause-texmex-to-crash-segmentation-violation) which involves overloading the way MATLAB handles TeX and LaTeX labels. Basically when you create a text label in a figure that has its interpreter set to TeX or LaTeX, MATLAB processes that string with a function called `tex.m`. This function creates a MATLAB string that is a fairly typical `.tex` file. It has a `\documentclass` and a `\begin{document}` and an `\end{document}`. The document class is `mwarticle` which is open source and is essentially identical to the article class with a few spacing and page layout changes. The MATLAB string is then passed to a closed source `.mex` file which does the processing and creates an image. It seems like the `.mex` file essentially calls some sort of `tex` program. This understanding presents two solutions.

The first is for the string to add packages. This is a little difficult since you need to include the path to the package. It is also not clear to what extent the program called by the `.mex` file is fully `tex` compliant. The string that MATLAB creates includes `\nofiles` and it is not clear how multiple passes are handles.

The second, and fun solution in my mind, is to overload `tex.m` to call your own TeX distribution. In this way you could do whatever you want with your MATLAB text labels. You could even include cross references and `pgfplots` and whatever else you want.