# Matlab Laprint and jpg,pdf figures

Tags: pdf, conversion, eps, matlab

For my thesis I would like to have the best quality and therefore I use `laprint.m` this generates an EPS and TeX file of my figures from Matlab (R2007b).

The following is installed on my computer (that is relevant for LaTeX):

Windows 7
TeXnicCenter
MiKTeX 2.9
Ghostscript 9.10

If I use **LaTeX => PDF** in TeXnicCenter then the labels of the axis aren't correct:

> S01

instead of

> power (W)

I guess that this has something to do with the `psfrag` options in the text file that is generated by laprint.

If I use **LaTeX => PS => PDF** in TeXnicCenter, then this works fine for the figures from Matlab.
But when I want to include another JPG, PNG, or PDF figure it doesn't work; TeXnicCenter gives the following error:

> Cannot determine size of graphic in figure.jpg (no BoundingBox).

Can someone help me?

Comment: If it is psfrag based then this will probably help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11839/using-psfrag-with-pdflatex

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i've solved by changing the format of my other figures to eps.

Comment: ah OK glad you got something working, if you'd like to self-answer it would close off the question rather than leaving it unanswered

Comment: I suggest the use of `matlab2tikz` and / or `matlab2pgf` and / or `plot2svg`.

Comment: Related/Duplicates [What is the best way to include Matlab graphics?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3995/15717) and [matlab figures with latex fonts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78477/15717)