# Problems converting matlab figures to pdf using /psfragfig

Tags: floats, matlab, psfrag

I am trying to include MATLAB figures as pdf files in my thesis. However after reinstalling my OS this doesn't work anymore and I am desperately trying to find a solution...

**What I do:** I use the function ***matlabfrag.m*** to export the .fig files to **.eps** and **.tex** files. This works perfectly fine. Then I create a temporary .tex file. This file contains the command

```
\psfragfig{figurename}
```

which replaces the standart MATLAB font with latex commands formulas etc. specified in the figurename.tex file. This temporary .tex file is then used to create a .pdf file with the command

```
pdflatex -shell-escape --src -interaction=nonstopmode tempfilename.tex
```

So far so good. Before I reinstalled my OS everything worked fine. Now I get the **Error**:

> Package pstool Warning: Execution failed during process:
>     ps2pdf -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dColorImag
>   eFilter=/FlateEncode -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress "70
>   00_CFC60_acc_single-pstool.ps" "7000_CFC60_acc_single-pstool.pdf"
>   This warning occurred on input line 16.
>
> LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T1+aett on input line 16.
>   (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ae/t1aett.fd
>   File: t1aett.fd 1997/11/16 Font definitions for T1/aett.
>   )
>   runsystem(echo "
>   === pstool: end processing ===
>   ")...executed.
>
> runsystem(rm -- 7000_CFC60_acc_single2.oldaux)...executed.
>
> [1
>   Non-PDF special ignored!{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
>   (./7000_CFC60_acc_single2.aux)
>
> LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
>
> )
>   (\end occurred when \ifx on line 16 was incomplete)

The .ps file looks perfectly alright. As the error suggests the problem must be .ps >> .pdf. I also stripped down the .tex file to a bare minimum, however only encountered other errors. Here is my temporary **tempfilename.tex** file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[crop=pdfcrop]{pstool}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \psfragfig[width=\textwidth]{7000_CFC60_acc_single}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: Do you know that you can export your Matlab figures to `pdf` directly?

Comment: Yes, I know. However in that case I do not have the latex font, only the standart matlab font for legends, axis-name, units etc.

Comment: You can also try `matlab2tikz` and/or `matfig2pgf`. There is also `plot2svg` which converts in to svg and then use inkscape to get tikz code. This is more reliable.  Read: [matlab figures with latex fonts](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78478)