# What is the best way to include Matlab figures in Latex

Tags: graphics, matlab

I know that this question is not new but as I look at the answers, like,

[What is the best way to include Matlab graphics?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3995/what-is-the-best-way-to-include-matlab-graphics)

[matlab figures with latex fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78477/matlab-figures-with-latex-fonts)

I realize that these threads are old. Since Matlab itself has included many functionalities to address this issue, I am wondering if the community can post some updated methods.

Also it will be nice if answers can address the issues one might face if one is using an online template for making \LaTeX documents like overleaf.com

Thank you

Comment: Given that one of those questions has updated information from March 2015, what additions to Matlab do you have in mind? Unless you have a more specific question, this is really a duplicate and it would be better to update the information in one of the earlier questions rather than asking the same thing again. (Or put a bounty on one of them, if that's more appropriate.) As it currently is, I think this should be closed as a duplicate precisely to avoid splitting the information relevant to this query between (more) different questions. Esp. if earlier info. is obsolete.

Comment: Giving an updated answer would be a good point. I've never been able to found a good routine able to handle both complex graphics and vector formats from matlab to latex.

Comment: I was particularly interested in using matlabfrag(.) for this purpose but it does not work. The Latex font is lost when I try to include figures in my beamer document. Since I am using overleaf.com, I thought of starting a new thread with a general title.

Comment: The thing is, that if there is new functionality, the answers to the other question should be updated or new answers added there. If there is no new functionality, then the answers there are all there is. Either way, duplicating answers here will just make the information (old and new) harder to find for people searching for this question. Note that there are no 'threads' here as such: it is a Q&A site and not a forum. As such, an old question which is the same as a new question is just the same. If there are now better answers, they are still answers to the same question.

Comment: If you have a *specific* question either about implementing a solution explained in one of the existing answers or about utilising some new functionality, then that would certainly be worth asking as a new question. But new answers to the general question belong with the general question and having two general questions would be unhelpful. [If you figured out the new functionality or someone else did, it would then be good for an answer to be added to the general question. But a specific question about problems doing that would be great.]